# Angularjs optional data in ng-options

Tags: angularjs

Hey I am having the following code :

```
data-ng-options='foo.title + " - " + foo.sequence for foo in foos'
```

The thing is, foo.sequence is optional and may be empty. If this is the case, I have a trailing hyphen.

Any idea how I can remove the hyphen if foo.sequence is empty ?

Thanks

Comment: did it finally work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could write a filter in this case:

```
<select data-ng-options='obj as (obj | writeOption) for foo in foos'>
```

```
app.filter('writeOption', function() {
  return function(obj) {
    if (obj.sequence){
        return obj.title + " - " + obj.sequence; 
    }else{
        return obj.title;
    }
  };
});
```

I did not try it, but I think it could work!